# How to make ucharclasses escape minted?

Tags: minted, ucharclasses

I am using [ucharclasses](https://ctan.org/pkg/ucharclasses?lang=en) to use multiple languages. I am using Noto Serif font for English. But ucharclasses is also changing minted codes into Noto Serif which should be Source Code Pro instead. How do I make ucharclasses escape minted?

**Update after egreg's comment:**

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[Latin, Bengali, Devanagari]{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}[BoldFont=Noto Serif Bold, ItalicFont=Noto Serif Italic]
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{SolaimanLipi}[BoldFont=SolaimanLipi Bold, Scale=1.2]
\newfontfamily\monof{Source Code Pro}[NFSSFamily=SCP]


\setTransitionsForLatin{\englishfont}{\bengalifont}

\setminted[C++]{fontfamily=SCP, frame=single, fontsize=\footnotesize}


\begin{minted}{C++}
#include<iostream>
\end{minted}
```

The last code block should load with Source Code pro. But it is loading with Noto Serif.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg  Updated my question

Comment: You can set \XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0   locally to disable the mechanism

Comment: your example can not be run as is, it is much better to provide it as a complete document  a form that people can run to see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\disableTransitionRules}
```

to locally disable the transition mechanism.

Alternatively, if you don't plan to use the `formatcom` option, you can do

```
\setminted{formatcom=\disableTransitionRules}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[Latin, Bengali, Devanagari]{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}[BoldFont=Noto Serif Bold, ItalicFont=Noto Serif Italic]
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{fontkalpurush.ttf}
\newfontfamily\monof{Source Code Pro}[NFSSFamily=SCP]

\setTransitionsForLatin{\englishfont}{\bengalifont}

\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\disableTransitionRules}
%\setminted{formatcom=\disableTransitionRules}
\setminted[C++]{fontfamily=SCP, frame=single, fontsize=\footnotesize}


\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{C++}
#include<iostream>
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've no preference about the methods. If your LaTeX is old, the `\setminted` strategy will work with no additional package. For the `\AtBeginEnvironment` you'd need `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can locally disable the xetex charclass mechanism:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[Latin, Bengali, Devanagari]{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}[BoldFont=Noto Serif Bold, ItalicFont=Noto Serif Italic]
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}
\newfontfamily\monof{Source Code Pro}[NFSSFamily=SCP]


\setTransitionsForLatin{\englishfont}{\bengalifont}

\setminted[C++]{fontfamily=SCP, frame=single, fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0
\begin{minted}{C++}
#include<iostream>
\end{minted}
}

\begin{minted}{C++}
#include<iostream>
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

(I changed the fonts as I did not have all the ones you used)